# Looking for a Wordpress accordion menu that fits my needs

Tags: wordpress, accordion

I've searched for a while now and haven't found any that fit all of my criteria.

Here's what I'm searching for exactly:

- An accordion style menu to put in a sidebar widget in Wordpress.
- The plugin must be able to generate a menu automatically from a specific Wordpress menu.
- There must be at least three levels in the menu (see image below).
- The use must be able to both expand a submenu **and** click the name to go to that page (see image blow).
- The menu always stays open to the sub-page the user is on.

It's completely irrelevant how the plugin looks, I'll re-style the CSS myself. As long as the plugin meets all these requirements for functionality.

[image: Mockup of menu]

Answer (score 1):

Use this HTMl

```
 <div id="MainMenu">
        <div class="list-group panel">
          <a href="#demo3" class="list-group-item list-group-item-success" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu">Item 3</a>
          <div class="collapse" id="demo3">
            <a href="#SubMenu1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#SubMenu1">Subitem 1 <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
            <div class="collapse list-group-submenu" id="SubMenu1">
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#SubMenu1">Subitem 1 a</a>
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#SubMenu1">Subitem 2 b</a>
              <a href="#SubSubMenu1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#SubSubMenu1">Subitem 3 c <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
              <div class="collapse list-group-submenu list-group-submenu-1" id="SubSubMenu1">
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#SubSubMenu1">Sub sub item 1</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#SubSubMenu1">Sub sub item 2</a>
              </div>
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#SubMenu1">Subitem 4 d</a>
            </div>
            <a href="javascript:;" class="list-group-item">Subitem 2</a>
            <a href="javascript:;" class="list-group-item">Subitem 3</a>
          </div>
          <a href="#demo4" class="list-group-item list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu">Item 4</a>
          <div class="collapse" id="demo4">
            <a href="" class="list-group-item">Subitem 1</a>
            <a href="" class="list-group-item">Subitem 2</a>
            <a href="" class="list-group-item">Subitem 3</a>
          </div>
           <a href="#demo5" class="list-group-item list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu">Item 5</a>
            <div class="collapse" id="demo5">
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Subitem 1</a>
            <a href="" class="list-group-item">Subitem 2</a>
            <a href="" class="list-group-item">Subitem 3</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Bootstrap JS files in Header.php

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

and styling

```
<style type="text/css">
            .list-group.panel > .list-group-item {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px
}
.list-group-submenu {
  margin-left:20px;
}
        </style>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this adresses absolutely none of my requirements for the functions of the menu. :/

Comment: okay you want the entire plugin/widget creation.. make this a bounty